# using the dir command writing a batch proccess

Tags: batch-file, dos

Im writing a batch file for work. basically my command right now navigates to a file path, then prints out the contents of the folder with the dir command.

Without giving the specifics away of what i am trying to print out here is the code im using

```
CD C:\Some folder\some folder2\some folder 3\some folder 4
DIR
```

now in "some folder4" there are 3 files. If i use the code

```
CD C:\Some folder\some folder2\some folder 3
DIR
```

It prints out fine that there is a folder "some folder4" in "Some Folder3", but as soon as i change the directory into the "some folder4" folder it says file not found instead of showing me the 3 files that are in it.

Any advice as to what would be causing this

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more specifics of what you're doing here (you're going to have to give away a bit more), but one thing you should definitely look at is the [`for /d`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) command instead of `DIR`.

You know you can use a `filespec` with the `DIR` (or `for`) command right?  Changing the directory isn't really the best choice - especially since drive and relative paths are assumptions.  [`cd h:\test\` doesn't switch drive if you're on `c:\`, but `dir h:\test\` will work no matter what drive you're on]

If your folders have spaces in them, it could be you need to escape the folder name with quotes (`cd "some folder4"`).

Comment: ok, a bit more specific, my goal is to have users on our network run this file once its complete to delete old credential files out of the folders. The folder path will always be a set path and there are 3 folders that i need to navigate to and delete folders. Basically i was going to cd to the first one, delete the files, then cd to the second, delete the files, cd to the last and delete the files. Im googling the for /d command, but can you give me an example as to how to use it to navigate to a certain path?

Comment: No need to google - click on it (I linked an explanation page).  Are you only deleting specific files or everything in the folder?  The `del` command also takes a filespec - no need to CD or DIR: `del .../folder4/*.*` will do the same.

Comment: Basically it will be specific files based on modification dates. Havent gotten that far as we have no final words on which files stay vs go. Was just creating a default framework where i could basically just drop the delete code in once i had the batch file navigating correctly. Im sorry i dont know where to click for the link.

Comment: nvm i found the link in the txt